# Ember: how to make one item binding instead of valueBinding="this" in list

Tags: javascript, ember.js

This code for all items works well:

```
 {{#each content.Questions}}
                <li>
                    <p>
                        <span class="index">{{Index}}. </span>
                        <span>{{Description}}</span>
                    </p>
                    <div class="chart">
                        {{#if Results}}
                          {{view App.ResultsArea valueBinding="this"}}
                        {{this}}
                        {{else}}
                          <div class="no-results">No data.</div>
                        {{/if}}
                    </div>
                </li>
{{/each}}
```

But I want to do the same for one item in content.Questions. E.g.:

```
 <li>
                        <p>
                            <span class="index">{{content.Questions.[0].Index}}.</span>
                            <span>{{content.Questions.[0].Description}}</span>
                        </p>
                        <div class="chart">
                            {{#if content.Questions.[0].Results}}
                              {{view App.ResultsArea valueBinding="content.Questions.[0]"}}
                            {{else}}
                              <div class="no-results">No data.</div>
                            {{/if}}
                        </div>
</li>
```

This `{{view App.ResultsArea valueBinding="content.Questions.[0]"}}` doesn't work. What should I write instead?

Comment: try this content.Questions.firstObject

Comment: @kumkanillam thank you! It works! But what about 2nd , 3d ... objects?

Comment: What is that? Looks ancient! Consider a current ember version if this is a new project! And I don't think there is a default way for indices expect the first and the last. Build yourself a component and some CP's. depending on your ember version.